# Select the ORDER BY ASC|DESC according to a value

Tags: mysql

I want to select the order by type according to a variable.

Something like this:
ORDER BY t.name case when @sort = 'asc' then ASC ELSE then DESC END

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @sort = 'ASC'
              THEN t.name
              ELSE 0
              END ASC,
         CASE WHEN @sort = 'DESC'
              THEN t.name
              ELSE 0
              END DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
ORDER BY CASE 
  WHEN @sort = 'asc' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.name)
  ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.name DESC)
END
```

or:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @sort = 'asc' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.name)
```

Comment: If this expression is not the most last subexpression in ORDER BY and t.name is not unique then this expression provides non-deterministic sorting, even when complete ordering expression provides the uniqueness. RANK() or DENSE_RANK() will be correct in such case.

Comment: @Akina if t.name is not unique then a simple `ORDER BY t.name` is non-deterministic also  but you use it in the statement that you propose!

Comment: If complete expression looks like `ORDER BY t.name @sort , t.id` then my expression provides deterministic output rather than your one. This is why ranking instead of enumeration needed.

Comment: @Akina If ... what? Where does `t.id` come from? I don't see it in the OP's code neither in your code. If it existed then `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.name, t.id)` would also be deterministic. Your code is as much deterministic as my code.

Comment: I define the condition when your code may produce non-deterministic output simply. In general, not for OP situation (from the other side OP have not told that this expression is complete/final).

Comment: @Akina your code is also non-deterministic if t.name is not unique. Introducing non-existing columns is not a solution. If t.id existed I would also use it in my code.